# DIV height doesn't working in pdfhtm iText?

Tags: java, html, css, itext, pdfhtml

I'm trying to put the image inside a Div. However, the height attribute doesn't get applied inside the generated PDF.

I wish to restrict the image height according to the DIV height. If the image is of smaller dimensions then the image shouldn't stretch, keeping the image dimension as it is.

**HTML:**

```
   <div style="height: 396.0pt !important; border: 1px solid red;"> 
   <img border="0" src="C:/naveed personal/eclipse-jee-oxygen-M2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/Docs_a0Lg000000XzFhgEAF_4/015g0000001O9Qf.JPG"> 
  </div>
```

[image: PDF]

Comment: Have u tried in px like "height:396px"

Comment: try to set the image with position: relative to 100% width and 100% height to the parent. maybe the image is greater than the 396 points of height and stretches the div

Comment: Yes. If you want the image to come out a certain height, you should give the image that height, not its container.

Comment: @ItFreak thanks for your comment, what happen when if the image is smaller dimension then DIV dimensions?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 yes.

Comment: @KhAnSaAb What do you _want_ to happen when the image is smaller than the div?

Comment: @MrLister i wish to keep it as it is.  no changes if its smaller than div

Comment: Than my Solution should work, just give the Image a Position relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to consider setting height to percentage of div.  Here's an example of how you would do that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

img.one {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

img.two {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Set the height and width in %</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<p>Original image:</p>
<img class="one" src="ocean.jpg" width="300" height="300"><br>

<p>Sized image (in %):</p>
<img class="two" src="ocean.jpg" width="300" height="300">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It partially works for me. :) Thank you @ekbrothers